# Modify \listofschemes output to match memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, memoir, chemstyle

I am using the `memoir` class with the `chemstyle` package.  I just observed that the output from my `\listofschemes` command has a different indentation and format than my `\listoffigures` output.

I tried to look into the definition of chemstyle and redefining the `\listofschemes` but I can't quite figure out how to modify the output to match the standard `\listoffigures` output.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}\tableofcontents*\clearpage
\listoffigures\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Schemes}\listofschemes
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter one}\section{Sec one}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test2}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\section{sec two}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test3}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test4}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test5}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\chapter{Chapter 2}\section{chap 2 sec 1}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test6}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test7}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test8}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\section{chap 2 sec 2}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test9}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test10}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

Looking at the `chemscheme.sty` file it even looks like the indentation should be zero, so I'm a little puzzled...

```
\newlistentry[chapter]{scheme}{los}{0}%
\cftsetindents{scheme}{0em}{2.3em}%
```

I'm using a whole list of other packages, but this recreates the problem.  Just in case it plays into the solution, I also use `floatrow`, `flafter` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the code example in section 9.3.1. of the `memoir` manual to create a "List of Schemes" -- this will override the actions of `chemscheme.sty`. (You may also want to add `\clearpage` before `\listofschemes`.)

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

% \newcommand{\listschemename}{Schemes}% already defined in chemscheme.sty
\newlistof{listofschemes}{los}{\listschemename}
\newlistentry{scheme}{los}{0}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}\tableofcontents*\clearpage
\listoffigures\clearpage
\listofschemes\clearpage
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter one}\section{Sec one}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test2}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\section{sec two}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test3}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test4}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test5}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\chapter{Chapter 2}\section{chap 2 sec 1}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test6}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test7}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test8}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\section{chap 2 sec 2}
\begin{figure}\caption{Test9}\includegraphics{blank}\end{figure}
\begin{scheme}\caption{Test10}\includegraphics{blank}\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]