# How to edit scheme numbering in a list of schemes?

Tags: tocloft, classicthesis, chemistry, chemstyle

I'm using `chemstyle` to create a list of chemical schemes (within `classicthesis`), but it numbers the list differently from my lists of Figures and Tables. Is there a way to change, for example, 1.1 into Scheme 1.1 and then edit the spacing so it matches everything else?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt, american,english]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[on]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage[textfont=it]{caption}
    \captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
    \setchemnum{format= \normalfont
                        \bfseries}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,listings,pdfspacing,floatperchapter,subfig,beramono,parts,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}


\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)



\begin{document}


\begingroup 
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax %removes gaps between lists

    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \listoffigures


    \vspace*{8ex}

    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
    \listoftables

    \vspace*{8ex}
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listschemename}{los}

\let\origaddvspace\addvspace%extra lines to stop breaking between chapter groups
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}%extra lines to stop breaking between chapter groups
    \listofschemes 
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{\origaddvspace{#1}}%extra lines to stop breaking between chapter groups

 \vspace*{8ex}
\endgroup 

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{chapter}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  {figure here}
  \caption[figure]{Figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  {table here}
  \caption[table]{Table}
\end{table}

\begin{scheme}[h]
  \centering
  {scheme here}
  \caption[scheme]{Scheme}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of Lists]
Update - This issue seems to arise in how chemstyle implements the tocloft `\newlistentry` command:

```
  \newlistentry[chapter]{scheme}{los}{0}%
  \cftsetindents{scheme}{0em}{2.3em}%
  \addtodef{\insertchapterspace}{}{%
    \addtocontents{los}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  }%
```

It calls the argument name as `{scheme}` and this creates many of the usual commands, so for example `\thescheme` works fine. However options that should act on this, such as `\cftschemepresnum` remain undefined. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry - I just realised this - will edit to amend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64658/modify-listofschemes-output-to-match-memoir-class) I added the following to the code before `\begin{document}`:

```
\newlistof{listofschemes}{los}{\listschemename}
\newlistentry{scheme}{los}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftschemepresnum}{Scheme~}
\setlength\cftschemenumwidth{8em}
\setlength\cftschemeindent{0.1em}
```

This causes an error on compile, that `scheme` has been previously defined, but if ignored, the document will compile with the changes to the table of schemes. It still seems like `chemscheme` isn't passing all the information to tocloft, but as a quick and dirty fix, this is the best I have!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst `chemscheme` does what it does well, it's not really that easy to integrate it into a complex set up like `classicthesis`. I'd probably simply define the `scheme` environment by hand at the appropriate point

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof[chapter]{scheme}{los}{List of Schemes}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\fps@scheme{tbp}
\newcommand*\ftype@scheme{3}
\newenvironment{scheme}{\@float{scheme}}{\end@float}
\newcommand*\schemename{Scheme}
\makeatother
\usepackage{classicthesis}
% Based on set up in classicthesis
\renewcommand{\cftschemepresnum}{\schemename~}%Tab.~}
\newlength{\schemelabelwidth}
\settowidth{\schemelabelwidth}{\cftschemepresnum~999}
\addtolength{\schemelabelwidth}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{scheme}{0em}{\figurelabelwidth}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofscheme

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  figure here
  \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  table here
  \caption{Table}
\end{table}

\begin{scheme}
  \centering
  scheme here
  \caption{Scheme}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Here I've copied the set up from `classicthesis` for tables and altered it for schemes.

Comment: Many thanks! That gets things working, but is there a way to call `chemstyle` and retain it's other functionality without `chemscheme`? This way I would avoid the compile error of having list of schemes defined twice?